# Ionic Cordova build failed with error Failed to apply plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

When I am running the command to build an Android project in Ionic -

`ionic cordova build android` or `cordova build android`

**Here is my** platform/android/project.properties

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-support-google-services/luxerus-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/luxerus-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:9.8.0
```

**OUTPUT WITH ERROR**

[image]

Comment: I guess one of your plugin is using the + to include dependencies which is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks! yes you're correct. To get it working, I had to fix many things, even after resolving that (plugin is using the +), check my answer..

Comment: should I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
  cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:+
```

To This:

```
  cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1
```

Comment: Whats on line number 16 on this file?

platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/luxerus-build.gradle

Comment: On line number 16 ->
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

Comment: As far as I know. "cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:+" means include all google service libs. So you should comment your line number 16. Its a conflict between two google services libraries.

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped me in getting things done. To get it working, I had to fix many things, check my answer.. for detail.

Answer (score 1):

The error is giving you an extra explanation:

> For input string: "+"

So the problem is the format you use for

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:+
```

If you'd use Android Studio, you'd also have a warning like

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and
>   unrepeatable builds
>
> Using `+` in dependencies lets you automatically pick up the latest
>   available version rather than a specific, named version. However, this
>   is not recommended; your builds are not repeatable; you may have
>   tested with a slightly different version than what the build server
>   used. (Using a dynamic version as the major version number is more
>   problematic than using it in the minor version position.)

So instead of `+`, give it at least a major version, like `11.0.+` (just test and see what version works for your project).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tried with different versions! Still same error.

Comment: How do we know, which version works? Is there any way to figure this out?

Comment: Well, I am not used to Ionic, but for Gradle, it's probably better to be the same as your other libraries, 9.8.0. The last version is [15.0.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped me in getting things done. To get it working, I had to fix many things, check my answer.. for detail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have another dependency on a google play services You have to fix ALL dependency version(s) to be more more specific like 11.0.+. and try to make all of them match, for example if firebase is using a different services version this could be your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your Android platform and adding it again:

`ionic cordova platform rm android`

`ionic cordova platform add android`

Then try running your build again.

Answer (score 0):

THE ABOVE ALL ANSWERS ARE VERY HELPFUL. THANKS! FOR POSTING ANSWERS.

> This worked for me by following these steps!!

**Step - 1)**

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

**Step - 2)**
Then on terminal..

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/
```

**Step - 3)**

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

**Step - 4)**
Commenting line (in file cordova-plugin-fcm/project-FCMPlugin.gradle, line number - 13)

```
//apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

**Step - 5)**
Commenting line (in file cordova-support-google-services/project-build.gradle, line number - 16)

```
//apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

**Step - 6)**
Add in file, project level build.gradle, line number - 35

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

**Step - 7)** 
In file project.properties (version 9.8.0 also work for me! in another project, for this I used 9.0.0)

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/luxerus-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/luxerus-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-support-google-services/luxerus-build.gradle
```

---

> Even after that, I got this error!

Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process processName Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I had this issue. I built the generated android project in the platform in android studio then I found the issue and solved this.

Follow this steps..

Inside the platforms folder, android/src/{package name}/MainActivity.java

Import the firebase library,
* import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

Inside the oncreate method, below super.oncreate(savedinstancestate),

Add FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

Last step,

Inside the platforms folder, android/res/values/string.xml,

Add ***

*** can be found in the googleservice.json file "client": [ { "client_info": { "mobilesdk_app_id": this value

---

Ref (for more detail): https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/142

---

Also add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

> That's it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resulted due to google services plugin applied more than once during build. This issue can be sorted out once [Add support for EnableGoogleServicesPlugin PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/438) is merged to Cordova Android which ensures cordova-support-google-services will only run once.